# Adding two time fields together

Tags: sql-server, time, casting

I have two columns within my table they are set as nvarchar fields but contain time values. 
one column is a time field one is the duration field
eg.

```
Time 1 = 15:05:22  (time field)
Time 2 = 00:02:00   (duration field)
```

I want to output Time 1 + Time 2 = `15:07:22`

I have tried `CAST(time1 as datetime)+CAST(time2 as datetime)`
but I get `1900-01-01 15:07:22.000`, and I don't want the date part. I can't use cast as time as I get an error I presume this is because the fields are set as nvarchar and not date/time?

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Adding time values makes no sense... How much is 10 pm + 11 pm?

Comment: Why nvarchar? Use proper data types and the problem is gone.

Comment: Looking at asker's history, I strongly suspect [tag:sql-server]. Please [edit] the question and add a suitable tag.

Comment: @jarlh, that's not true. Many rbms doen't have a Time data type, and a DateTime data type will have an implicit date part, that is what is trying to avoid

Comment: And if this is SQL Server, then the most appropriate data type for trying to store time *spans* (as opposed to times of day, which is what the `time` data type is designed for) is, unfortunately, usually some type of integer, storing a count of whatever units you want to work down to (e.g. seconds or milliseconds)

Comment: @mnieto, <sql> tag alone implies ANSI SQL. ANSI SQL has date, time, timestamp and interval data types. Still adding _time_ values makes no sense.

Comment: will you have duration like `00:61:00` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast **the result** to `time` to get rid of the date portion:

```
DECLARE @time_txt varchar(8);
DECLARE @duration_txt varchar(8);
SET @time_txt = '15:05:22';
SET @duration_txt = '00:02:00';

SELECT CAST(CAST(@time_txt as datetime) + CAST(@duration_txt as datetime) as time);

-- yields the time value 15:07:22.0000000
```

If you need this as a string (for example, in `hh:mm:ss` format), you can use [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) with the appropriate format option:

```
...

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), CAST(@time_txt as datetime) + CAST(@duration_txt as datetime), 108);

-- yields the string 15:07:22
```

---

PS: In general, you should use `time` columns for `time` values instead of `varchar` columns. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have a really good data type for durations (time spans).

Answer (score 1):

select dateadd(second,datediff(second,0,time1),time2) as Time3 
from your_table